# Alternative to session in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, query-string, state-management

I have 2 page in project, let say 'UserGrid' and 'User Details'.
'UserGrid' show a list of users. On clicking the ID column of the row, partner get redirected to 'User Details' page, which show details of user.

While partner click on ID, I store the UserID in session and access it in 'User Deatils' page to fetch user details.

Now let say partner open user with ID 1234 1st, then he open 3456 in next tab. So now we have 2 'User Details' page with 2 different user data, but in session we have only 2nd tab UserID as 1st data was overwritten. So now if I will update the 1st user details, in background it will update the 2nd user details as in session 2nd userID is present.

How to manage it in best way, except Query String?

Comment: Best way *is* querystring

Comment: Tahnks @Hans Kesting, I have already mentioned in question, if I can use any other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to show the ID in the querystring, you can store values in [ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx). These are page-instance-specific, will survive postbacks, but will not survive redirects.

So maybe you need to do:

- Store the ID in session
- Redirect to the details page
- Check ViewState:

  - if there is a value, use that;
  - else copy from Session into ViewState

Answer (score 0):

In these situations you must use **QueryString**

```
<asp:HyperLink   
    ID="HyperLink1"  
    runat="server"  
    NavigateUrl="~/Webform2.aspx?UserId=1"
    Text="User"  
</asp:HyperLink>
```

On **User Details** page get it

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32( Request.QueryString["UserId"]);
    // get user and display it
```

}

More information :

[HttpRequest.QueryString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Passing variables between pages using QueryString](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString)

Comment: Use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Convert.ToInt32. Otherwise, it will throw exception if UserId is not valid.